# Improving a logistic regression model in R

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, classification

I have to devise a model in R, capable of predicting the type of a disease, which is a categorical dependent variable (three possible values), through several continuous and categorical, some of the latter being ordinal or dichotomous, independent variables (details of the dataset below). I used the multinom() function to create a first model, but how can I assess about how good this model is? And how can I compute the true positive, false positive, true negative and false negative?

Below there's a detailed description of the dataset, which has more than 6000 entries, and the process through which I created the model.

```
**Dependent variable**
type of disease : [T, D, M]

**Independent variables**
year
week
no : number of occurrences
nso : number of severe occurrences
average temperature
humidity
rainfall
age
gender : [M, F]
race : ["Chinese", "Indian", "Arabic"]
job : ["Student", "General worker", "Housewife", ..., "Other"]
```

---

### EDIT

As suggested in the first answer, I created training and test sets (...)

```
smp_size <- floor(0.7 * nrow(dat))

set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(dat)), size = smp_size)

train <- dat[train_ind, ]
test <- dat[-train_ind, ]
```

(...) and then the model, with the multinom() function:

```
formula = type~year+week+no+nso+temp_avg+humidity+rainfall+age+gender+race+job+town

model_multinom <- multinom(formula, train)
```

And afterwards I've done some prediction:

```
prediction = predict(model_multinom, data=test)
summary(prediction)

type2  type1  type3 
1171   88     3298
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate your data into training and test sets and predict type of a disease for test dataset using model you have built on training dataset. This is the way for quality assessment of the model.
Some examples and interpretations of multinomial regression models:

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/mlogit.htm

http://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-multinomial-regression-models-in-r/